# Access to header information by $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, authorization, angular-resource

I send a request server-side by $resource which is inside my factory.
In the return object there many information, but I'd like to have access to the authorization in the headers.
I tried to print the returning object by console.log() but I dont see any headers and authorization in console. What should I do?

```
controllers.controller('ProfileSettingCtrl', function ($scope,User) {
     User.get({id: 'me'}, function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            $scope.profile = res;
        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for `$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> Success callback is called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments.

Seems like you can just get the headers with `function (res, headers) { console.log(headers); }`

Comment: thanks. the header argument was good. but when I run console.log(headers). It doenst return a function like this ```function (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      var value = headersObj[lowercase(name)];
      if (value === void 0) {
        value = null;
      }
      return value;
    }

    return headersObj;
  }```

Comment: @AliSaberi why would you expect it to return a function?

Comment: I also add photo to my post to make my explanations more clear.

Comment: @AliSaberi try `responseHeaders('Authorization')`

Comment: it gave me null! I doentt know why? as it is on photo, it should exist

Comment: @AliSaberi this is for the response headers only ... the request headers are something that *you* are setting!

Answer (score 0):

According to the $resource docs, the header is passed as second argument to your success callback.

> It's worth noting that the success callback for get, query and other methods gets passed in the response that came from the server as well as $http header getter function, so one could rewrite the above example and get access to http headers as:
>
> `var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
>   User.get({userId:123}, function(u, getResponseHeaders){
>     u.abc = true;
>     u.$save(function(u, putResponseHeaders) {
>       //u => saved user object
>       //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
>     });
>   });`

If you want to use the header information, you have to use the success callback. Otherwise I always advice to use promises, which you can chain and pass around: 
`User.get().$promise.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);`